# The name '<name>' does not exist in the current context on MVC 4.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm having what i guess it's some dumb problem, but still can't figure it out.

I'm having some trouble with HTML in a MVC 4.0 web application. This is the code:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" value=@item.ID id="id" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Do something</button>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(function (e) {
    $("#id").click(function () {
        var buttonValue = $(this).val();
        $("#modalBody").load("@Url.Action("Operation", "Controller", new { id = buttonValue })");
    });
  });
</script>
```

I'm getting this error ("The name 'buttonValue' does not exist in the current context") when I try to send the value to the controller ( ... new { id = buttonValue }).

Any information that helps me would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You are mixing Javascript and Razor markup. You can't reference the variable like that.

Comment: The Razor syntax is calculated when the page renders, therefore it cannot know what the button value will be during the click event. Try and build a url with a querystring. eg 'www.myurl.com/controller/action?id=' + buttonValue;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `buttonValue` as a parameter in the `load` function:

```
$("#id").click(function () {
    var buttonValue = $(this).val();
    $("#modalBody").load("@Url.Action("Operation", "Controller")",
        { 'id': buttonValue });
});
```